# jQuery loop through text occurrences

Tags: javascript, jquery, usability

I need to be able to loop through the next occurrence of a given text on a page. Just like the most common 'find' function on almost every software (F3 - find next).

I'm trying to to that using jQuery but can't make it work by any means. Tried: NextAll(), next(), closest() (which seems bugged), find(), eq(), children(), etc., etc., etc.

Below is a sample that do work but it goes to the last element on the page and do not loop through.

```
function scrollMe(tow){
    var targetOffset = $("*:contains('"+tow+"'):last").offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
}
```

To make it clear my page has a set of rows(divs) with text inside. Every time a user click on this row it must gently roll down (or up) to the next row with the occurrence of the text (if any).

Sample:

```
<div onclick="scrollMe('hello');">hello</div>
<div onclick="scrollMe('world');">world</div>
<div onclick="scrollMe('foo');">foo</div>
<div onclick="scrollMe('hello');">hello</div>
<div onclick="scrollMe('bar');">bar</div>
```

Indeed it should be enclosed by jQuery but it's just to illustrate.

Comment: What is :last supposed to do here? Do you always want the set to contain exactly one element (i.e. the last one)?

Comment: Paulo: I see two issues with this: First, what is your definition of "next" occurrence? Is it any occurrence which is above the scroll position, or is it the next relative to some other position on the page? You need to clarify this.

The other issue is a little worse: Your selector will match all parents to any element containing the text. So you will have everything from <html>, through <body>, <div id="container"> (perhaps), all the way down to the containing element. Seems like a pretty tough problem.

Comment: kato: the use of last is just for simulate the behaviour. Its should, as explained, loop sequentially trhought all occurences. And Linus: By next occurence i mean the next bellow (if any) or if it is on the bottom of the page it should start back from the beggining. The text used in this project is an addres wich has 0% chance of matching other thing but pure text on the html. Anyway the definition of the scope (such as a wrapper) shoud be used instead if the '*' obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a working example of scrolling to the next occurrence and highlighting it](http://jsfiddle.net/KTwm3/6/).

Since you're going to use a variable as the input to contains, I'd recommend skipping the selector. It's fast, but you're going to have trouble keeping the variable input sanitized.

This will, for example, highlight all the text occurrences of 'two' ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KTwm3/4/)):

```
jQuery(function($) {
   var findText = 'two';
    $('*').filter(function() {
        return $(this).children().length < 1 && $(this).text().indexOf(findText) >= 0;
    }).addClass('hilite'); 
});
```

To make this work with some sort of find next functionality, you would need a variable to keep track of the current index, and some sort of trigger:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   // stores the currently highlighted occurence
   var index = 0;
   var findText = 'sed';

   // you could do this inside the click as well, here, it's cached/faster
   // inside click, it would be more dynamic and prevent memory leaks
   // just depends on your needs
   // you would also want to start with a parent element as $('*') is costly!
   var $occurrences = $('*').filter(function() {
       return $(this).children().length < 1 && $(this).text().indexOf(findText) >= 0;
    });

    // remove existing highlights, then find the next occurrence and highlight it
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
       if( index == $occurrences.length-1 ) { index = 0; }
       $occurrences.find('span.hilite').replaceWith(findText);
       var $next = $occurrences.eq(++index);
       $next.html( $next.html().replace(findText, '<span class="hilite">'+findText+'</span>') );
       $(document).scrollTop($next.offset().top-35);
       return false;
    });

    // scroll our trigger link when the screen moves so we can click it again
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#trigger').offset( {top: top, left: 0} );
    });

});
```

Comment: Nice Kato, I adapt your code and now it works fine. Althroug the overhead of the .filter being triggered every time (on my version) the response is satisfatory (on a 600 record page). thx.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for this you should use something to find the text in the table and then scroll to that position.

Ive made a jsfiddle to show you how to find the top position of the table cell that contains a certain text [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wMLw8/1/)

This fiddle alerts the top position of both words "hello" in the order that they appear. You could possibly use break() to find only the first one.

You should be able to take this and implement your own program around it, using something like jQuery's scrolltop() to scroll your screen to the next word.

Comment: I got it, but to control wich is the next one I must set and control a global var and set break every time. Nice try.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ScrollMe(tow) {
    var id = 'scroll_counter_' + tow;
    var indexStr = 'index';
    var $counter = $('#' + id);
    var animationLength = 1000;
    if ($counter.length == 0) {
      $counter = $('<div></div>').attr('id', id);
      $counter.appendTo('body');
      $counter.data(indexStr, 0)
    }
    var index = $counter.data(indexStr)
    var $items = $("*:contains('"+tow+"')")
    var $item = $($items.get(index))
    $counter.data(indexStr, (index + 1) % $items.length)
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $item.offset().top}, animationLength);
}
```

Enjoy.
Every call to ScrollMe() with a given string finds the next occurrence of the string.
If it's called with different strings, the results aren't reset (though they can easily be).
The code needs to be modified a bit to support strings containing non-alphanumeric characters.
I'm sure you'll be clever enough to find out how to highlight/change the color of the selected element.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is *exactly* what you're after, but it should provide a starting point:

http://jsfiddle.net/massivepenguin/pnu37/18/

I've added a search form so you can find specific words...